# Filter using dplyr based on condition as a loop

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two data frames. df1

```
    col1
 1  apples
 2 oranges
 3  apples
 4  banana
```

and df2

```
   setID    col1
1      1  apples
2      1 oranges
3      1  apples
4      1  banana
5      2  apples
6      2 oranges
7      2 oranges
8      2  apples
9      3 oranges
10     3  grapes
11     3  banana
12     3  banana
13     4  apples
21     4  oranges
31     4  apples
41     4 oranges
```

I used filter from dplyr package to narrow down df2 by df1$col1[1] and putting the result in tempdf

```
> tempdf <- df2 %>% group_by(setID) %>% filter(any(col1==df1$col1[1]))
> tempdf
    # A tibble: 12 x 2
# Groups:   setID [3]
   setID    col1
   <dbl>   <chr>
 1     1  apples
 2     1 oranges
 3     1  apples
 4     1  banana
 5     2  apples
 6     2 banana
 7     2 oranges
 8     2  apples
 9     4  apples
10     4  oranges
11     4  grapes
12     4 oranges
```

It needs to be grouped by setID because I’m trying to see which setID matches to df1 the best. Since setID = 3 doesn’t have any apples it is omitted in the first iteration. I want this to be a loop so that everytime its run the tempdf gets filtered more.

For the next element it should df1$col1[1:2] so that it checks “apples” and “oranges” in order. So after the second iteration tempdf should look like this.

```
setID    col1
   <dbl>   <chr>
 1     1  apples
 2     1 oranges
 3     1  apples
 4     1  banana
 5     4  apples
 6     4  oranges
 7     4  grapes
 8     4 oranges
```

The next iteration should check df1$col1[2:3] so it always check the previous element. “oranges” and “apples” this time.

```
 setID    col1
   <dbl>   <chr>
 1     1  apples
 2     1 oranges
 3     1  apples
 4     1  banana
```

Once it reaches just one unique setID the loop should end. And the result will be that df1 matches with setID=1 of df2.

Comment: This question is quite unclear. Please state up front what you're trying to accomplish, show the desired end result, and let the forum decide how to get you there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution could be based on selecting `setID`having maximum match on col1 as:

```
df2 %>% group_by(setID) %>% mutate( maxMatch = sum(col1==df1$col1)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
   filter(maxMatch == max(maxMatch)) %>%
  select(-maxMatch)

#Result
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  setID col1   
  <int> <chr>  
1     1 apples 
2     1 oranges
3     1 apples 
4     1 banana
```

Comment: I like this answer a lot. But is there an approach that would filter df2 by going through each element in df1 one by one? Assume that you get df1 not as a whole but element by element. So in real time you are trying to narrow down df2 to a possible match. Kinda like auto complete on search engines.

Comment: @Nix The iteration is happening on `df2` and it will be a single iteration. Eventually in any solution every element of `df2` has to be compared with `df1`.

Comment: @Nix It's good to accept an answer so that it will be helpful to future users.  have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: the reason why i asked if it could be compared element by element is that ideally I would only have df2 as a complete data frame. The df1 is gonna be a subset of df2, mostly an approximate match and very rarely an exact match. And df1 is not gonna be complete when I start to compare it to df2. And the more df1 gets complete by adding more elements to it the better a match I can find to it from df2. Sorry if this is too messy to understand. And thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea to filter the `setID`. In this case it will return the `setID` as 1 directly without a loop. The downside is it will not return any results if there are no exact match of all the items in `col1`. However, it should be much faster than the for-loop approach.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df1 %>% summarise(col1 = toString(col1))

df4 <- df2 %>%
  group_by(setID) %>%
  summarise(col1 = toString(col1)) %>%
  semi_join(df3, by = "col1")
df4
# # A tibble: 1 x 2
#   setID col1                           
#   <int> <chr>                          
# 1     1 apples, oranges, apples, banana
```

**DATA**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "    col1
 1  apples
                  2 oranges
                  3  apples
                  4  banana",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = "   setID    col1
1      1  apples
                  2      1 oranges
                  3      1  apples
                  4      1  banana
                  5      2  apples
                  6      2 oranges
                  7      2 oranges
                  8      2  apples
                  9      3 oranges
                  10     3  grapes
                  11     3  banana
                  12     3  banana
                  13     4  apples
                  21     4  oranges
                  31     4  apples
                  41     4 oranges",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This idea is good. But it doesnt accomplish what I'm trying to get at. I need the elements checked one by one. Exact match is not a must. An approximate match is enough.